# Add loading indicator to google maps infoWindow

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, scriptmanager

Currently, when a user clicks on a location marker on our map screen, a page method is called to retrieve additional information from the server.  When the page method is successful, the results are used to define the contents of an infoWindow which is displayed on the map.  In situations where the page method is slow, we would like the infoWindow to be displayed immediately, but with a loading indicator.  After the page method is successful, the content of the infowWindow would then be updated.

So far, my naive approach has been to initially create the infoWindow with a loading indicator and display this initial infoWindow with a call to open(map), and then update the contents of that infoWindow after the page method is successful.  This approach, however, does not work, since the map canvas is not updated until after the page method has completed (the initial version of the infoWindow is therefore never displayed).

----- page code -----

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&client=MY_CLIENT&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   function initialize_map() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(...);
      // set remaining map properties...
   }

   window.onload = function () {
      initialize_map();
   }

   function DrawPoint(loc) {
      var marker = GetPointMarker(loc);
      // set remaining point marker properties...
      marker.setMap(map);

      var showPointInfo = function (evt) {
         var infoWindow = infowindowList[loc];
         if (infoWindow == undefined)
         {
            GetPointInfoStart(loc);
            GetPointInfo(loc);
         }
      };

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', showPointInfo);   
   }

   function GetPointInfoStart(loc)
   {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var content = // initial content with loading indicator
      infoWindow.setContent(content);
      // set remaining infoWindow properties...
      infoWindow.open(map);
   }

   function GetPointInfo(loc)
   {
      // call page method to retrieve data for infoWindow
      PageMethods.GetMapPointInfo(..., OnGetPointInfoSuccess, OnFailure);
   }

   function OnGetPointInfoSuccess(result) {
      eval(result);
      var infoWindow = infowindowList[loc];
      var content = // final content with retrieved data
      infoWindow.setContent(content);
   }

</script>
```

----- code behind -----

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).EnablePageMethods = true;
   ...
   base.OnInit(e);
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetMapPointInfo(...)
{
   // retrieve point information from server...
   return jsonString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in how the initial content was being defined.  With the content now being defined correctly, the approach (as above) is now working.